# Is there a shortcut for namespacing singleton classes

Tags: php, namespaces, static-methods

My current code is as following:

```
namespace Libraries;

class_alias('Libraries\ORM', 'ORM');

class ORM 
{
    public function __construct() {}

    static public function someMethod()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

I thought I could shortcut the namespace as you can see above, so I only needed to call the `ORM::someMethod();` instead of `\Libraries\ORM::someMethod();`

(I am using the ORM class in another namespace, lets says 'Project')

Is this possible or what is the right solution?
I know that I could store the class in a global namespace, but then I still need to use the global slash like: `\ORM::someMethod();`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply [alias](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) the classname when you are importing it:

```
namespace SomethingEntirelyDifferent;

use Libraries\ORM as ORM;

ORM::someMethod();
```

Comment: True, but do I need to include the `use Libraries\ORM as ORM;` in every file I need to use the ORM? Is there another way?

Comment: No, you can create your own autoloader or if you use composer in your project you can autoload your classes trough the composer autoloader configuring the composer.json

Take a look at:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php
http://getcomposer.org

Comment: Okay thanks, I will dive into the autoloader stuff! Thanks for your help, I will accept the answer in few minutes ;)